# Reading large excel files in Python and UnicodeDecodeError:

Tags: python, excel

I am new to Python and I'm trying to read a large excel file in python. I converted my xlsx file to csv to work with pandas. I wrote the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('filepath.csv')
df = csv.parse("Sheet")
df.head()
```

But it gives this error:
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 28: character maps to <undefined>`

Can you please tell me why it gives this error? Or do you have any advice to read large excel files? I also tried to work with `openpyxl` module, but I couldn't use `read_only` because of version of my Python.(I am using Python 2.7.8)

Comment: Have you tried `pd.read_excel` yet?

Comment: I tried but it's so slow

Comment: What I usually do is save the excel into Unicode text file then use pd.read_csv(filename,sep='\t,encoding='utf-16-le') to open the text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
pd.read_csv('filepath.csv',encoding ='utf-8')
```

There are many other encoding techniques like `encoding = 'iso-8859-1'` or `encoding = 'cp1252'` or `encoding = 'latin1'`. You can choose as per your requirement.

Comment: When I do that, this error occurs:CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 28

Comment: Try using delimiter.  `pd.read_csv('filepath.csv',sep=None,encoding ='utf-8')`

Comment: It worked, thank you. But it just read 5 rows, there are much more than 5 rows in my file.

Answer (score 1):

Save the excel into Unicode Text File with Microsoft Excel.

[image]

Open the file with this line:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename,sep='\t',encoding='utf-16-le')
print(df.head())
```

Comment: Go to save as option and select **Unicode Text** as **Save as type**. Check out the image I added to the answer I posted.